# RazorEngine templating emails

Tags: razor, razorengine

Is it possible declaring properties with razor engine like

```
     Hello @customername
```

instead of like

```
      Hello @Model.customername
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you need the @Model to retrieve the customername.
You could create a variable in the beginning of your code and populate it with the customerName, but either way you need the @Model at least once.

```
var customerName = @Model.customername;
Hello @customername
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it would be great, if I can declare this variables "outside of template" before rendering it.

Comment: You can create "helper" methods outside of your code, but they do need an input parameter so you cant declare everything outside of the template.
I assume you use this RazorEngine so take a look here on how to use a external helper method: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20Custom%20Base%20Templates&referringTitle=Documentation